# Phalcon: How do I use my custom Validation class with forms?

Tags: php, phalcon

I created a Validation class that supports the validation of multidimensional arrays and I'd like to use it, but I don't know how Phalcon retrieves the validation instance.

how do I do that?

This is my MultiDimensionalValidator class:

```
/**
 * Validates inputs with multidimensional names such as "names[fr]name'.
 *
 * @package Intlist\Validator
 */
class MultidimensionalValidator extends Validation
{
    /**
     * @param \Phalcon\Validation $validation
     * @param string $attribute
     *
     * @return Validation\Message\Group|void
     */
    public function validate($validation = null, $attribute = null)
    {
        $this->_data = $validation->_data;
        $this->_messages = $validation->getMessages();

        foreach ($this->_validators as $validator) {
            $validator->validate($this, $attribute);
        }

        return $this->_messages;
    }

    /**
     * Support for multidimensional array.
     *
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getValue($attribute)
    {
        $parts = $this->extractKeyParts($attribute);
        $value = $this->_data;

        while ($name = array_shift($parts)) {
            if (!array_key_exists($name, $value)) {
                return null;
            }

            $value = $value[$name];
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Extract the parts from a flattened multidimensional key.
     *
     * @param string $flattened
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function extractKeyParts($flattened)
    {
        $pos = strpos($flattened, '[');

        if (!$pos) {
            return [ $flattened ];
        }

        $first = substr($flattened, 0, $pos);
        $remainder = substr($flattened, $pos);

        preg_match_all('#\[([^\]]+)\]#', $remainder, $matches);

        return array_merge([ $first], $matches[1]);
    }
}
```

And this is a usage:

```
foreach ($this->domain->getLanguages() as $language) {
    $name = new Text("names[$language][name]");
    $name->setLabel($t('common.label.category_name') . " ($language)");
    $name->addValidator(new MultiDimensionalValidator([
        new PresenceOf(['message' => $t('validation.category_name.required')]),
        new StringLength([
            'max' => 255,
            'messageMaximum' => 'validation.category_name.messageMaximum'
        ])
    ]));
}
```

The MultiDimensionalValidator class is used as a validator here, but I would really like to use it as the Validation instance of the form.

Comment: Are there examples in the Phalcon docs? Or, to make your question clearer, can we see your validation class? If you can add an attempt to wire it into a form also, that would be ideal, and the question can then be reopened.

Comment: Is this clearer now?

Comment: Yes, I think so, good stuff! Voting to re-open (it will need a few more votes but it should get them).

Comment: I updated the class with working code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your custom validator in conjunction with a form, then you need to add the element to the form like so:

```
$form->add($name);
```

Per the documentation (http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/forms.html#validation) you can then use the isValid method to validate your data:

```
if (!$form->isValid($_POST)) {
    foreach ($form->getMessages() as $message) {
        echo $message, '<br>';
    }
}
```

Note, however, that the Phalcon validation component (http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/validation.html) is independent of forms. In other words, it needn't be a part of a form. It could be a part of a model instead, or it could be a stand-alone class, as in the following example:

```
$validation = new Phalcon\Validation();
foreach ($this->domain->getLanguages() as $language) {
    $validation->addValidator(new MultiDimensionalValidator(...));
}
$messages = $validation->validate($_POST);
if (count($messages)) {
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo $message, '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tim, sorry the example is not clear enough, but I already know that, the problem is that validation of inputs with multidimensional names is not supported by Phalcon. In my example Phalcon would try to validate a value with the key "names[fr][name]", which is actually an array in $_POST e.g. $_POST['names']['fr']['name'] and not $_POST['names[fr][name]']. My validator takes care of this situation, and I would like to use it on the form itself, not on some inputs.